# Group isomorphism from quotient ring $R/P$ to $P^n / P^{n+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, group-isomorphism

I am struggling with the following claim:
There is a group isomorphism $R/P \cong P^n/P^{n+1}$ for any natural number $n$, where R is a ring (commutative with unit) and $P$ is a prime ideal.

My attempt:
Let $\alpha \in P^n\setminus P^{n+1}$. There is an isomorphism $R/P \rightarrow \alpha R/\alpha P$ (multiplication with $\alpha$ is surjective and has $P$ equal to the kernel).
Because $\alpha R \subset P^n$ the inclusion induces a homomorphism $\psi:\alpha R \rightarrow P^n/P^{n+1}$ with $ker(\psi) = \alpha R \cap P^{n+1}$ and $im(\psi) = \alpha R + P^{n+1}$.
I thus want to show that $\alpha R \cap P^{n+1} = \alpha P$ and $\alpha R + P^{n+1} = P^n$ to conclude that $\psi$ factors to give an isomorphism $\alpha R/\alpha P \rightarrow P^n/P^{n+1}$.

If $x\in \alpha P$, $x=\alpha p, p\in P$ then $x\in \alpha R$ and $x \in P^{n+1}$. If $x \in \alpha R \cap P^{n+1}$, $x=\alpha r, r\in R$, then because $x\in P^{n+1}$ and $\alpha \not\in P^{n+1}$ we find that $r\in P$ and we have shown the first equality.

As both $\alpha R$ and $P^{n+1}$ are contained in $P^{n}$ also their sum is, which gives one inclusion of the second inequality.

However I don't know how to show the last inclusion $P^n \subset \alpha R + P^{n+1}$.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Seems like this is not true in this generality (see comments), I need it for the case where $R$ is the ring of integers $D \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ (e.g. a Dedekind domain)

Comment: I don't think this is true in this generality. Take $R = k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3)$ and $P = (x,y)$ with $k$ a field. Then $R/P \cong k$, which has dimension $1$, but $P/P^2$ is $2$-dimensional. In particular, if we take $k$ to be a finite field, then $R/P$ and $P/P^2$ don't even have the same cardinality.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn thanks for your example. I got this from the book "Number Fields" by Daniel A. Marcus, Theorem 22a) where he just brushes over this fact. So I tried to prove it as a general statement. Seems like I relaxed the conditions a bit too much.
The original theorem assumes $R$ to be the ring of integers $D \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ (if I recall correctly, at least that is what I need it for).

Comment: Looks like you want $R$ to be a Dedekind domain but not necessarily a UFD then?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes, Dedekind domain would be a good assumption.

Comment: Consider the discrete valuation associated to $\mathfrak p$, a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$. Let $x$ have valuation $1$. The map $r\mapsto rx$ maps from elements of valuation $i$ to elements of valuation $i+1$, and it has an inverse $r\mapsto rx^{-1}$. This seems to help, I would think?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Unfortunately I am not familiar with valuations. My definition of ring of integers is „roots of monic polynomials with integer coeffiecients.“, following the book by Zagier.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra) The valuation we want to take is $x$ has valuation $i$ if it lies in $P^i$ but not $P^{i+1}$. Extend to all of the (non-zero elements of the) field by taking $v(x)=-v(x^{-1})$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I understand what valuation you are describing. After reading up a bit on valuations I think this is exactly the valuation we get from the fact that the localization $R_P$ is a discrete valuation ring (as $R$ is Dedekind domain), i.e. $R_P = {0} \cup {x \in \operatorname{Frac}(R_P)| v(x)\geq 0}$.
But I still can't see how the map $r\mapsto rx$ helps. I am not even sure in what step of my proof I am supposed to apply this.
If $x\in P^n$ has valuation $\geq n$ the inclusion is clear, but if $v(x)=n$ then I would have to somehow relate $x$ to $\alpha$ which I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following proof supposes that your familiar with ideal arithmetic in Dedekind domain (It seems impossible to avoid it, since you have counter examples for general $R$).

Since $\alpha\in P^n$, we have $\alpha R\subset P^n$, and since $R$ is a Dedekind domain, it is equivalent to $P^n\mid \alpha R$. Hence $\alpha R= I P^n$ for some ideal $I$. Note now that by choice of $\alpha$, the $P$-adic valuation of $\alpha R$ is exactly $n$ (since $\alpha\notin P^{n+1}$). In particular, $I$ and $P$ are coprime. Therefore, $I+P=R$.

Now $\alpha R+P^{n+1}=P^n ( I+ P)=P^n R=P^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know what you mean by "valuation of $\alpha R$", if you mean that the valuation of every element in $\alpha R$ is $n$ then I don't think this is true (as $P^{n+1}\subset \alpha R$).
But anyways, we can also argue that $I\not\subset P$ (by choice of $\alpha$) and that thus $I+P=R$ because $P$ is maximal (which is equivalent to prime if $P\neq0$ in a Dedekind domain).
Also, is it true that the existence of $I$ follows from the unique decomposition into prime ideals?

Comment: the valuation of an ideal at a prime $P$ is the power of $P$ in the (unique) decomposition of a nonzer o ideal into product of powers of nonzero prime ideals. "Yes" for the existence of $I$, but in fact, the decomposition into prime ideals follows from the principle $'I_1\subset I_2\iff I_2\mid I_1"$....